# Can several windows be open in a MDI form with different window states at the same time?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windowstate

I did a MDI Winforms application and noticed behaviour that I have a question for.

If one of the forms is opened with a Maximized Window State and another form is opened with a Normal Window State, the form Window State that used to be Maximized is changed to Normal.

Can several windows be open in a MDI form with different window states at the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDI permits only one child window in the maximized state, the active window.  It *forces* such a window back to the normal state when you make another window active, regardless if that other window is maximized or not.  Or in other words, you cannot have a active window in the normal state on top of a maximized non-active window.  There's no workaround for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It would be nice to be able to do that. Maybe in future releases of Visual Studio they will allow it. In the mean time I placed code in the "Enter" event of the forms so the correct Window State will be activated when focus is placed on any of those forms.